# How to run JMeter using jmx file in the azure pipelines with/out docker

Tags: docker, jmeter, azure-pipelines

Can anybody help me to understand how to build and run JMeter script in azure pipelines with docker or without docker?

Answer (score 0):

> How to run JMeter using jmx file in the azure pipelines with/out docker

You could run JMeter using `jmx` file in the azure pipelines by command line task without docker.

JMeter can be launched in non-GUI mode as follows:

```
jmeter -n -t /path/to/your/test.jmx -l /path/to/results/file.jtl
```

But since the hosted agent did not install JMeter, we could not run the jmeter command line directly. We need download and install the JMeter on the our private agent.

Please check this document [Configuring Jmeter Tests in VSTS/TFS (Azure DevOps) and publishing Results](https://medium.com/@ganeshsirsi/configuring-jmeter-tests-in-vsts-tfs-azure-devops-and-publishing-results-dcdd7b451cb9) for some more details.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is JMeter hosting step in a hosted agent is mandatory? Can I have any other way I can go for.

Comment: @SanjeevThakur, I am afraid the answer is yes. We have to use self-hosted agent instead of the hosted agent. Since the JMeter is not the built in software in the hosted agent. And run Apache JMeter load tests with Azure DevOps has some other limitations: https://qautomation.blog/2019/05/29/run-apache-jmeter-load-tests-with-azure-devops/

Answer (score 0):

Depending what you have installed on your Azure agent you can go for:

1. Running JMeter in [command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)
2. Running JMeter via [Maven Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-maven-plugin)
3. Running JMeter in [Ant Task](https://github.com/jfifield/ant-jmeter)
4. Use one of thousands of [JMeter docker images](https://hub.docker.com/search?q=jmeter&type=image)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I go with the Ant task, Is installing Jmeter on Azure agent mandatory one. Can I use the batch scripts to download JMeter in azure pipelines for building JMX files?